Send email via AWS SDK
I try to send email via AWS SDK
I have accessKey and secretKey.
var accessKey = "";
var secretKey = "";
var region = RegionEndpoint.USEast1; // Use the appropriate region

var credentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
var config = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceConfig { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1 };


using var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials, config);

var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
{
    Source = "email@email.com",
    Destination = new Destination
    {
        ToAddresses =
            new List<string> { "email@email.com" }
    },
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = new Content("Test email"),
        Body = new Body
        {
            Html = new Content
            {
                Charset = "UTF-8",
                Data = "<h1>Hello</h1><p>This is a test email sent using Amazon SES.</p>"
            },
            Text = new Content
            {
                Charset = "UTF-8",
                Data = "Hello, this is a test email sent using Amazon SES."
            }
        }
    }
};

try
{
    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(sendRequest);
    Console.WriteLine("Email sent! Message ID: " + response.MessageId);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);
}

But I got error message:

The security token included in the request is invalid.

Is it possible send email If I have only AccessKey and SecretKey ?
Or I have to generate token ?

Have you tried doing anything else at all with those AWS credentials?

No. Good Idea to check it

You only need your key and secret key values. Try setting creds using Environment variables or in .aws/credentials on the DEV Machine where your .NET code is running. Either way will work.
Then you can use this .NET code to test SES functionality. I just ran it to ensure it works.
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/SES/Actions
When you look at the source code in above example, you will see no need to do:
var credentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
var config = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceConfig { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1 };


using var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials, config);


Thanks for comment. What name should have env variables for these parameters?
